# Java Spring DSL Is it possible to use two transformers with Message.class but different Generics in it?

Tags: java, spring-integration-dsl

I have a code similar to this and my main problem that in first transform method the generic for the Message.class is  and for the second one is  (because in the first one we transforming the payload from Message.class from MessageEvent.class to String.class) and as I specifying the same class (Message.class) in the second transform message spring applcation context also expect Message, but getting Message and throwing exception below. I can't specify payload classes directly, because we also have we also use Headers in Message.class, that we need.

```java
@Override
  protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory, sourceTopic)))
            .publishSubscribeChannel(channel -> {
                channel.subscribe(flow -> flow
                    .transform(Message.class, firstClass::someMethod)
                    .transform(Message.class, secondClass::someMethod)
                    .intercept(doLog(log, Level.INFO, "OUT"))
                    .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
                        .headerMapper(jmsHeaderMapper)
                        .destination(outputQueue)));
    }
```

Exception message:

```
    no suitable method found for transform(Class, firstClass[...]method)
    .transform(Message.class, firstClass::someMethod)
    ^
    method BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition.transform(String, Consumer) is not applicable (argument mismatch; Class cannot be converted to String)
    method BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition.transform(Object, String) is not applicable (argument mismatch; String is not a functional interface)
    method BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition.transform(MessageProcessorSpec, Consumer) is not applicable (argument mismatch; Class cannot be converted to MessageProcessorSpec)
    method BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition.transform(Class, GenericTransformer) is not applicable (argument mismatch; invalid method reference incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Message)
    method IntegrationFlowDefinition.transform(GenericTransformer, Consumer) is not applicable (argument mismatch; Class cannot be converted to GenericTransformer)
```

I found solution with workaround how to directly specify generic for the class ("(Class<Message>) (Class<?>) Message.class") and it is works correctly, but I don't think that it is the best approach. How can I resolve this issue without that workaround?

If i specify methods without expected class I'm getting classCastException, because of the same issue

```java
    @Override
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()))
            .publishSubscribeChannel(channel -> {
                channel.subscribe(flow -> flow
                    .transform(firstClass::someMethod)
                    .transform(secondClass::someMethod)
                    .intercept(doLog(log, Level.INFO, "OUT"))
                    .handle()
```